# Content Item tokens always coming through empty in Projection Query

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to create a Projection Query that has a Title Part filter based on a property of the current content item - let's say the Display Text (`{Content.DisplayText}`) for example.

[image]

The query is not working and when I debug the solution and set a break point on the GetFilterPredicate method of the StringFilterForm class the token value is always coming through as an empty string. It's as if it's not being resolved. I am seeing the same behavior for all the tokens in the Content Items group.

Other tokens are working just fine, like the QueryString (`{Request.QueryString:*}`) token for example.

Why are the Content Item tokens always coming through empty in my query filter? I'm using Orchard v.1.7.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 years later, but in Orchard 1.9.2 you can query based on the current content item using the token:

```
{Request.Content.*}
```

I was missing the Request part of the token. Not sure if this worked at the time I originally asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works. Tokens are not meant in this context to generate query constraints on the content item properties. Tokens can only be used there to provide values for parameters of the query. If you want to filter on the title of a content item, use a title part record filter.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I am trying to use the token in a Title Part Record filter as parameter of the query. I added a screenshot of my filter setup. The token is always an empty string when the filter is evaluated.

Comment: As I said, that won't work. You'd need projections to transform your tokens into dynamic SQL where clauses. That's simply not how it works at all. The query string parameter is an entirely different matter as it's one fixed value from the environment that can get injected as a parameter (as opposed to a database column).
Fortunately for you, and as I said in my answer, there is a perfectly good Title filter that you can use to implement the exact scenario you are describing.